# Checking username before signing up Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After using snapshot.exists(), username will always return as available upon signup. How can I alter my code to properly check whether or not a username has already been taken?

Here is a snippet of the json under "users" in the database:

```
{
  "UserID#" : {
  "credentials" : {
  "name" : "testuser",
  },
 }
}
```

My code currently looks like:

```
let usersDB = Database.database().reference()
var taken = false
  usersDB.child("users").child("credentials").queryOrdered(byChild:"name").queryEqual(toValue: username.lowercased()).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() {
            taken = true
            print("Username is not available.")
            usernameAlert()
        } else { 
          print("User is available")
        }
```

No matter if the username is already taken on the database, the snapshot will say it does not exist.

Solutions I've tried with no success: 
[check if the username exist in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906207/check-if-the-username-exist-in-firebase) 
[Query users in Firebase to check if username exists during sign up process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134789/query-users-in-firebase-to-check-if-username-exists-during-sign-up-process)
[Firebase querying for unique Username swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971814/firebase-querying-for-unique-username-swift)
[Check if user exists with username using Swift and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907667/check-if-user-exists-with-username-using-swift-and-firebase)
[Swift & Firebase | Checking if a user exists with a username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442114/swift-firebase-checking-if-a-user-exists-with-a-username)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON under `users/credentials` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Updated question to include JSON snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're now checking under each child node of `/users/credentials` for a property named `name`. What you instead want is to check each child node of `/users` for a property at `credentials/name`, which you do with:

```
usersDB.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild:"credentials/name").queryEqual(toValue: ...
```